# JavaScript Files Crash Visual Studio. Clearing "_refenences.js" fix the issue

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, crash, visual-studio-2015, references.js

Recently, when I open a JavaScript file on my solution (or open a razor CSHTML with some JavaScript on it), in Visual Studio 2013, after a while I get the error `"The JavaScript language service has encountered an error and has been shut down"` and I loose code highlighting and coloring for javascript. In VS2015 Pro, the issue is more drastic as the whole Visual Studio crashes and wants a restart.

I saw a similar problem for VS2013 in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965008/the-javascript-language-service-has-encountered-an-error-and-has-been-shut-down), but didn't help me.

Now following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746495/visual-studio-2015-crashes-when-opening-javascript-files), I cleared my `_references.js` file. This works. I have no problems if I do this (as far as I can tell) - I even have intellisense. However, when I right click and `Update Javascript References`, it looks like VS2013 keeps working fine but VS2015 starts crashing again. I would like to use VS2015.

My question is,

- would there be any side effects to cleaning the contents of this file `_references.js`?
- why would this happen in the first place?
- Is there any other fix other than manually deleting the contents of this auto-generated file?

The extensions on my Visual Studio 2013 Professional installation are Web Essentials, Resharper 9 and Telerik. I have a relatively clean installation of Visual Studio 2015 Professional, with only ReSharper 10 on it.

Comment: did you manage to resolve the issue? Its bothering me right now and I am about to go crazy.

Comment: @Emin: I'm sorry to say that it was a clean installation of both Windows and Visual Studio that solved it for me.

Comment: I removed all non-sense references (e.g. plugin language files), I also removed Angular.js references as well as some Bootstrap references that I am confident I can do without intellisence. Recompiled, and everything is going smoothly till then. I have not carried out a clean install since 2009 and no way this issue will force me to! :)

Comment: I respect that :-)